# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects - lambda

Tags: python, django

I use Django FactoryBoy for testing. This is my code:

```
import Factory

class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
    FACTORY_FOR = User
    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user' + n)
    email = 'test@test.com'
    password = 'sha1$$a4483ce7bd7083999bef6a74117a443239e67fac'
```

and here my error:

> ```
> username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user' + n)
> ```
>
> TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest solution is

```
username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user' + str(n))
```

Why you're getting this is because String and Int are two separate types in Python and thusly a type conversion is in order.

The cleaner approach would be

```
username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "user{0}".format(n))
```